# How to setup path variables for Ionic 4 android build?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

[This is my environment variables in path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwiQD.png)

I have created an ionic 4 application and I am having issues when I use `ionic Cordova build android --prod --release`
this throws some errors, but I think it's not the matter. The built app doesn't work on my phone and I don't know why. I don't have android studio installed but I have android SDK tools installed this is where they are located

1. Android-Sdk-Tools are located here: C:\Users\klejv\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
2. Also i have them here C:\tools

I would like to know how to set this up clearly as I am not able to build any apk from my command tool.
[This is Command Tool, during the build process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb5l6.png)

Comment: it will sound too simple but did you follow this guide? https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

Comment: what are the errors? the path thing that you are seeing are both point at the same place so if you are thinking that the (deprecated) bit is an issue, I don't think it's that.